# Displaying conventional math theta using kmath

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

Bookman is one of my favourite fonts, and I was happy to discover the kmath package. Although it's designed for use with the greek language:

```
\usepackage{kmath, kerkis}
```

gives you bookman font and bookman math, besides a very ellegant integral sign. I was very happy with the package until I had to use the command:

```
$\theta$
```

the problem is that it renders a theta which is very different from the conventionally used theta. I know that the conventional theta exists in kerkis, but it is inserted only in textmode and in the middle of words.

Is there any workaround to display a nice theta?

(One that worked for me was very brute-force and ugly: loading the package upgreek and forcing an uprigth theta. But that results in lots of complains by TeX for loading too many math alphabets, and, also, well, theta is upright while the surrounding math is slanted)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kmath, kerkis}

\begin{document}

\Huge
$\theta\vartheta$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes these are theta but, I think he means it more like the one in the picture here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta